# Best practice for initializing many variables based on file path

Tags: python

Amateur python programmer here, first post on stackoverflow. I have a set of files that I need to analyze. Each file is found in a unique location. To run the analysis, I need to initialize a large number of variables for every file. Fortunately, many (but not all!) variable values can be inferred from the respective file path.
As an example, for the file path `path_one = "~/foo/cow/old/brown/file.txt"` I would need variables

```
species = "cow"
colour = "brown"
popularity = 6
```

while for the file path `path_two = "~/foo/horse/young/gray/file.txt"` I would need variables

```
species = "horse"
colour = "gray"
popularity = 8
```

What are the best practices for doing this?

Currently, I am passing each file path to a convoluted function that uses if-elif-else constructs to build a dictionary `the_dict` in the following manner:

```
if "horse" in path and "young" in path and "gray" in path:
    the_dict["popularity"] = 8
```

Then I pass the dictionary (along with many more variables that can NOT be logically inferred from the file path) to my analysis function.
Is there a better way to do this? One that does not rely so heavily on if-elif-else constructs and one that does not require passing so many variables to the analysis function (a number that is already drastically reduced due to using the dictionary)? Also, accessing `the_dict` over and over in my analysis function seems ugly and unwieldy, though this is more of a cosmetic complaint.

Comment: I would rethink using the folder structure to pass parameters. This would make it difficult to test things. On the other hand a `file.json` or yaml with your config co-located with your `file.txt` would allow you to test things more easily

Answer (score 0):

That would really depend on how many variables you want to fill in, and how convoluted and versatile you desire your initialization. For the example that you've shown, maybe this is elegant enough

```py
import os
from collections import defaultdict
presets = dict()
presets[("horse", "gray")] = dict(popularity=8)
presets[("cow", "brown")] = dict(popularity=6)

# ...
path = "~/foo/horse/young/gray/file.txt"
path = os.path.normpath(path)
parts = path.split(os.sep)
species, age, colour = parts[-4:-1]

preset = presets.get((species, colour), dict(popularity=-1))
popularity = preset.get("popularity")
print(species, age, colour, popularity) # horse young gray 8
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get it a bit more compact (and OS-independent) you might want to have a look at the (python-standardlib module) `Pathlib` for the paths...
(note that this does not care about the order at which the options appear at the moment!)

```
from pathlib import Path

# define all available options
options = {
    6: {"cow", "brown"},
    9: {"horse", "gray"}
    }

def get_popularity(p):
    # loop through options
    for popularity, vals in options.items():
        # check if folder-structure contains all relevant values
        if set(Path(p).parts).issuperset(vals):
            # return as soon as one of the options fulfills the criteria
            return popularity
        



path_one = "~/foo/cow/old/brown/file.txt"
path_two = "~/foo/horse/young/gray/file.txt"

for p in (path_one, path_two):
    print(get_popularity(p))
```

Comment: Why would the popularity level decide the animal type? Why not vice versa?

Comment: hah, not sure... just thought that's what he's trying to do...   as I understood it it was about how to get this more compac: `if "horse" in path and "young" in path and "gray" in path: the_dict["popularity"] = 8`    (and using set-comparison avoids the lengthy `if` constructs)

Comment: Well if I would want two animals with popularity 6, that would be a bummer